# Nodejs way to access object properties in elegant idiomatic way

Tags: node.js

Some JSON is parsed into object and I need to access it, but I'm not 100% sure if the property will be there all the time. So I have something like this:

```
if (val && val.date && val.date.title) {
 doSomething(val.date.title)
}
else {
 doSomethingElse()
}
```

It seams that node.js that's it's like python and people like to simplify the things in more elegant manners. And have the feeling I maybe don't use the nodejs language properly, it gets the job done, but probably this is non-idiomatic code and the there exist idiomatic code. I tried to search for it but couldn't find direct answer. One other way achieve the same thing would be try/catch, but still it doesn't feel the idiomatic way

```
try {
  doSomething(val.date.title)
}
catch (e) {
  doSomethingElse()
}
```

Or maybe this is it and I just look too deep into things.

Comment: Although it appears to reduce your code, I would seriously vote against the try catch approach for an if/else situation. Exceptions as their name suggests are supposed to be for situations that wouldn't follow a predictive plan. It's not entirely wrong in that case, but in my opinion, looks a bit too tweaky.

Comment: Javascript hasn't native support for that feature. You should use additional library, such as lodash. Lodash has `get` function which returns an object value or null if it doesn't exist: `if (_.get(val, 'date.title'))`.

Comment: @zoubida13 what if the function should stop execution, unless `doSomething` can be auccesfully invoked

Comment: @Yerken I agree with you, but in that case you should explicitly define the exception you are catching. What if the exception is raised in doSomething and has nothing to do with val being undefined? this is my point.

Comment: @zoubida i kinda agree, i tried to use exceptions really for something more broken and not just something which i'm expecting a bit. Probably I will go with lodash, i used it before just forgot about it. Performance is not issue, the calls take 2s seconds for the all the responces from the servers and if I will call this on 6 fields it will not affect the 2s anymore. It's more for development helper so it will not go to production anyway

Comment: @zoubida13 yes, correct. So with careful implementation and on case by case basis, exception based implementation can be acceptable :) plus, I believe using non native libraries, such as `lodash` better be avoided, unless absolutely necessary or there is a true value. In this particular case, deep down traversal can be effectively implemented manually as well

Comment: @zoubida the try catch is bit thermonuclear aproach, i'm very tempted with the lodash

Comment: @muni764 yes if properly controlled the exception mechanism is very powerful.
I think we can all agree that it would be nice if JS simply interpreted accessing properties of undefined items as undefined objects.

Comment: @Yerken I agree as well that using a third party library (which adds another dependency to your app) for just a case of refining the written code (because lodash doesn't do anything magical, it just encapsulates manual long expressions into smaller functions), is probably best avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the function `get` from the small module `utjs`.

```
var ut = require('utjs');

var obj = {a: {b: [{c:1, d: 2}, true]}};

ut.get(obj, ''); // Returns { a: { b: [ [Object], true ] } }
ut.get(obj, 'a'); // returns { b: [ { c: 1, d: 2 }, true ] }
ut.get(obj, 'a.b'); // returns [ { c: 1, d: 2 }, true ]
ut.get(obj, 'a.b[0]'); // returns { c: 1, d: 2 }
ut.get(obj, 'a.b[1]'); // returns true
ut.get(obj, 'a.b[0].c'); // returns 1
ut.get(obj, 'a.b[0].missing'); // returns undefined
ut.get(obj, 'a.b[0].missing.something'); // returns undefined
```

Your can get the same functionality using the same function from the known module `lodash`, but it is slower.

Comment: I'm more interested about ut.get(obj, 'a.b[0].missing.something');

Comment: Even the disution to question has some valid points worth reading

Comment: The sample was updated, the function will return undefined in that case.